# WEKA Cut off value for kNN and Dynamic Time Warping

Tags: machine-learning, weka, nearest-neighbor

I'm using Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) as a distance measure for K Nearest Neighbour (kNN) machine learning algorithm. In [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index.html) the kNN algorithm has cut off value to act as an early abandon if the distance that is currently being calculated is bigger than a previous distance.

My problem is that I am not sure how to implement this early abandon with DTW without doing all of the calculations. How can I know for certain that the final distance will be bigger than the cut off?

Answer (score 0):

You could try some lower bounding for Dynamic Time Warping, like the LB_Keogh lower bound: http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/LB_Keogh.htm

The basic idea is to findi a distance measure that is a lower bound of DTW, and is computationally (a lot) cheaper.